# How do I check if page ID matches ID in array during loop?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops

I've written a custom query in WordPress that loops through 4 different page ID's and pulls out the page titles. What I need to do is check if the page being viewed is one of those ID's and if that's the case don't display that specific title. I know I basically need to do a check against the current page ID and the ID's in the array as it loops, but how would I go about doing that?

```
<?php

$service_args = array (
    'post_type'=> 'page',
    'post__in' => array(87,106,108,110), // The page ID's
    'orderby' => 'ID', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$servicesquery = new WP_Query( $service_args );

if ( $servicesquery->have_posts() ) {
   while ( $servicesquery->have_posts() ) {     
   $servicesquery->the_post(); 
?>

<h4><?php echo the_title(); ?></h4>

<?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current page/post Id using `<?php get_the_ID(); ?>`. Find current page id and exclude it from the array that you are preparing.

```
$posts_array = array(87,106,108,110);
$current_page_id = get_the_ID();

if ( ($key = array_search($current_page_id, $posts_array)) !== false) {
    unset($posts_array[$key]);
}

$service_args = array (
    'post_type'=> 'page',
    'post__in' => $posts_array, // The page ID's array
    'orderby' => 'ID', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$servicesquery = new WP_Query( $service_args );

if ( $servicesquery->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $servicesquery->have_posts() ) {
        $servicesquery->the_post();
        ?>
        <h4><?php echo the_title(); ?></h4>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that code results in the same title being echoed out infinitely. What I need is to check against the ID numbers in the `'post__in' => array(87,106,108,110)` and if one matches the current page ID exclude it from the results.

Comment: @liamjay66: I have edited my answer. Please go through it. Now I am finding the current page id and excluding it from the query itself. Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the page id outside of the while loop, like this:

```
var thisPageId = get_the_ID();

while ( $servicesquery->have_posts() ) {
    if ( $servicesquery->post->ID != thisPageId ) {
        echo the_title();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem with the help of this post by using `array_diff` to check against the ID's: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108697/use-post-in-and-post-not-in-together

```
$this_post = $post->ID; // Get the current page ID 
$exclude = array($this_post); // Exclude the current page ID from loop
$include = array(87,104,106,108,110); // ID's of pages to loop through

$service_args = array (
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post__in'  => array_diff($include, $exclude),
    'orderby'   => 'ID', 
    'order'     => 'ASC'
);
```